# Зачем эти элементы в стандартном шаблоне asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Пытаясь понять сгенерированный cshtml Layout я нашёл что удаление этих строк никак не влияет на внешний вид сайта и его работу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на Home контроллер и index метод. Это я понимаю, но не понимаю зачем.

Вот сайт с этими элементами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот без

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зачем? Не думаю что всё просто так.

Comment: Сожмите (сузьте) окно браузера - увидите разницу в поведении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это дополнительное меню с пунктами из header сайта, которое появляется на устройствах с маленькими дисплеями вместо горизонтальной панели. Это адаптивная верстка.

[image: на маленьком окне]

Кстати разница есть и на большом окне - после удаления этих тегов название "WebApplication1" пропадает.